# Get Post Response in Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

i am trying to post my form data via `service` but if i am trying to get the response in console i am finding `undefined` can you suggest me what mistake i am committing,
i am new to angular so finding difficult to catch the issue.Here is my code

```
commonApp.service('CommonServices',function($http){

        this.saveData=function(DataToInsert){
        $http({
            method  :"POST",
            data    :DataToInsert,
            url     : 'myurl',
            //headers :{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(programApiResponse){

            console.log(programApiResponse);
            return programApiResponse;


        }).error(function(programApiResponse){

            return programApiResponse;

        });

        };
    });
```

and my controller

```
$scope.makeprogram=function(){
        //console.log($scope.programdata);

        $scope.ProgInsResponse=CommonServices.saveData($scope.programdata);

        console.log('1'+$scope.ProgInsResponse);
    }
```

Comment: your myurl sending response correctly in postman or soapui?

Comment: yes, all my data is posting, i am not able to log the response

Comment: Yes that will be undefined because ajax takes a while to fetch data and console runs way before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't returning the promise at

```
this.saveData = function(DataToInsert){
    $http({
    ...
```

This should probably be

```
this.saveData=function(DataToInsert){
    return $http({
    ...
```

Then if you can add your own handlers

```
CommonServices.saveData($scope.programdata)
    .then(...)
```

Last but not least if you have a half decent browser you can just log objects, don't log strings.

```
CommonServices.saveData($scope.programdata)
    .then(function(){
        console.log(arguments);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is async nature issue. Try this

```
$scope.makeprogram=function(){

        CommonServices.saveData($scope.programdata).then(function() {
           console.log('1'+$scope.ProgInsResponse);
       }); 
    }
```

Since you are returning promise you need to wait before response comes.